# KKT formulation

Tags: convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, karush-kuhn-tucker

How to reformulate the following problem

$$min \frac{1}{2} (x_1-a_1)^2+ \frac{1}{2} (x_2-a_2)^2$$
$$s.t.  \mathbf{1}^Tx=1$$
      $$ ||x||_2\leq2$$

as the following system of KKT conditions:
$$(1 + \mu)x = a + \lambda\mathbf{1}$$
$$\mu \geq 0$$
$$\mathbf{1}^Tx=1$$
$$ ||x||_2\leq2$$
$$ (||x||_2-2)\mu=0$$

where $$ x = (x_1, x_2)^T$$ and $$ a = (a_1, a_2)^T$$

Actually, the only thing which is not clear to me is how the first term in the KKT system is obtained, the rest is pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first equation represents the KKT condition

$$
\nabla f_0 (x) + \sum \lambda_i\nabla g_i(x) + \sum\mu_i\nabla h_i(x) = 0
$$

You can easily verify that $\nabla f_0 = x-a$. The rest of the calculation should be straightforward; it might helpful to represent the second constraint as $||x||_2^2 = x^Tx \leq 4$.

Also, do not get tripped up if you have a $2\lambda$ instead of $\lambda$, since $\lambda$ is just a variable you can simply redefine $\lambda' = 2\lambda$, much like absorbing all extra constants into one constant of integration in calculus.

Comment: Thanks, got it. If you see my formulation, here I have a problem with the sign of $$\lambda$$ in the first KKT equation. I suppose I can manipulate the first constraint in the primal like this: $$ -x^Tx+1 = 0$$? This would influence to have ... $$+\lambda \mathbf{1}$$ on the right side of the equality in the equation. Correct?

Comment: I think you have a typo in your comment. Also, the use of multipliers is a little non-conventional; typically $\lambda$ corresponds to inequality constraints.

Regardless, the sign of $\lambda$ can be reversed without concern. This is because $h(x)=0$ is equivalent to $-h(x)=0$. The sign of the multipliers corresponding to the inequality constraints, however, cannot be flipped as these multipliers are constrained to be positive.